# Prove on cardinality of a countable subset of real numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm asked to prove that, for a countable subset of real numbers, either (a) the cardinality of such subset with non-negative real numbers equals the cardinality of natural numbers (i.e. that resulting intersection is countable) or (b) the cardinality of such subset with negative real numbers equals the cardinality of natural numbers (i.e. that resulting intersection is countable), this is:

Let B be countable subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Prove that either $card(B\cap[0,\infty))=card(\mathbb{N})$ or $card(B\cap(-\infty,0))=card(\mathbb{N})$.

Any insights on suitable approaches to prove this? I'm struggling to put this into formal and general terms.

Many thanks.

Comment: Use that a subset of a countable set is again countable or finite. It cannot be the case that both of these intersections are finite when the original set is not.

Comment: Put in other words: for any sets $A,B$ if $A\cup B$ has infinitely many elements then $A$ or $B$ must be infinite (else if they both are finite, then their union is finite as well).

Comment: Note that $B\cap [0,\infty)\subseteq B$.

Comment: Thank you all! This suggestions together with @fleablood structured thought was of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it into simpler words and concepts.

They are asking you to show that if you have a countably infinite set, and you partition it into two subsets, then at least one of the two subsets (or maybe both) must be countably infinite.

Note that a subset of a countably infinite set is either countable or finite (that should be a proposition you have proven already).  So you have four options.

1. Both subsets are finite
2. One subset is finite and the other is countable infinite
3. One subset is countably infinite and the other is finite
4. Both are countably infinite.

You have to prove 1) is impossible.

Note that the union of two finite sets is finite (that should be a proposition you have proven already).  So if 1) is true than the original set is the union of two finite sets and therefore the original set was finite.

That contradicts that you were told the original set was countably infinite.

Comment: Thank you! This structure was 90% of the answer as it enabled me to link the ideas in a relatively elegant manner.